# Error Code: AccountDidNotSerialize. Error Number: 3004. Error Message: Failed to serialize the account. Vec<String>

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, rust, anchor-lang

I am facing an error on adding line `Vec<String>,` type or `String` type.
Error:
[image: error pic]

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ModifyLedger<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub ledger_account: Account<'info, Ledger>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub wallet: Signer<'info>,
}
```

program function:

```
   pub fn add_limited_list(
        ctx: Context<ModifyLedger>,
        limited_pk_list: Vec<String>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        for each_limited_pk in limited_pk_list.iter() {
            if ctx
                .accounts
                .ledger_account
                .limited_stage_list
                .iter()
                .find(|&pk | pk == each_limited_pk)
                == None
            {
                ctx.accounts
                    .ledger_account
                    .limited_stage_list
                    .push(each_limited_pk.to_string());
            }
        }

        Ok(())
    }
```

Account:

```
#[account]
pub struct Ledger {
    pub limited_stage_list: Vec<String>,
    pub timebound_stage_list: Vec<String>,
    pub public_stage_list: Vec<String>,
    //pub uri: String,
}
```

Comment: it would help so see how you are initializing the account that is failing. this is most likely an error with allocated space for the account and not properly handling dynamic data types on accounts

Comment: You can view my entire smart contract [here](https://github.com/abdullahqureshi5050/mint-nft-anchor-pda-candymachine/blob/main/programs/mint-nft-anchor-v3/src/lib.rs).

Comment: I have assigned ```space = 82``` to the account. The code breaks down if I changes this number. Code works for all types ```u8```, ```u32```, ```u64```, ```i64``` but not for ```String``` and ```vec<String>``` 

Code Snippet: 

```#[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = wallet,
        space = 82,
        seeds = [
            b"new_seed",
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub ledger_account: Account<'info, Ledger>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I increased the `space` that didn't worked initially. What worked for me is that after I increased the space (i.e `space = 1024`) and then deleted `target` folder, fetch new keys using `anchor keys list`, replaced it in `declare_id` and in `anchor.toml`, and then redeployed the the program using `anchor build` and `anchor deploy`. That worked for me.

```
#[account(init_if_needed,payer = wallet,space = 1024,seeds = [b"new_seed",],bump)]    
 pub ledger_account: Account<'info, Ledger>
```